# How to find where an environment variable is set?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Say I have some environment variable `PROJECT_HOME`. I want to find out which file it is set in. How do I do this?

Comment: Should have posted this in Superuser - users who are able to, feel free to move it over there.

Comment: You mean from where it was set

Comment: That variable may be set not only by the files in your $HOME loaded at login time, but also by other files `sourced` by those files in your $HOME.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
find $HOME -type f -exec grep -Hn 'PROJECT_HOME' {} \;
```

Answer (score 14):

```
grep -r PROJECT_HOME /etc $HOME
```

will probably find it.

Answer (score 2):

I like using [ack!](http://betterthangrep.com/) in these kind of situations. I would change into the likely super directory and do an `ack PROJECT_HOME`.