# Determine how environment variable was set

Tags: python, environment-variables

In Python I can access an environment variable as:

```
os.environ['FOO']
```

I would like to know if the variable was set previously via `export` or if it was set only for the current python script like so:

```
FOO=BAR python some-script.py
```

Basically I want to only use `FOO` if it was set like in the line above and not permanently defined per `export`.

Arguments to the python script itself unfortunately are no option here. This is a plugin and the parent application does not allow passing custom arguments it does not understand itself.

I was hoping I somehow could access the exact and full command (`FOO=BAR python some-script.py`) that started python but it appears like there is nothing like that. I guess if there was a feature like this it would be somewhere in the `os` or `sys` packages.

Comment: How the shell determines what env to pass to a executed program isn't something a program should care of, so the FOO=BAR part is only processed by the shell, it's not exposed in any way, so what you try to do is not possible.

Comment: That's just as bad as functions behaving differently depending on how they were called. It's a Terrible Idea™. Why are you forcing the caller to use certain conventions, which may in fact be extremely cumbersome? Being able to `export FOO=BAR` and then *not* having to repeatedly pass the argument is a convenience tool; why deny your users to use it?

Comment: Because, as described, using environment vars simply is a workaround for not being able to pass custom arguments. Still it is an argument and should behave like one. Defaulting to something that might have been defined last week is no option. We're talking here about managing remote systems and which system is being wiped and re-installed is nothing I want to have taken from environment just because of a user error.

Comment: [How to determine where an environment variable came from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813/56041), [How to find where an environment variable is set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8058487/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 4):

The environment is simply an array of C strings, there is no metainformation there which helps you find out whether or not the invoking shell had the variable marked for `export` or not.

On Linux, you could examine `/proc/(pid)/environ` of the parent PID (if you have suitable permissions) to see what's in the parent's permanent environment, but this is decidedly nonportable and brittle.

Spending time on this seems misdirected anyway; let the user pass the environment variable in any way they see fit.