# How to find shell environment variable

Tags: linux

Is there anyway to find where to define the linux environment variable? When I print the environment variable using:

```
env
```

the output is:

```
PATH=/home/local/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/home/hldev/software/sbt:/home/local/jdk1.8.0_111/bin:/bin:/home/local/gradle-3.5.1/bin:/home/local/node-v6.9.2/bin:/home/hldev/bin:/home/hldev/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64/bin:/home/local/go/bin:/home/local/gradle-5.3/bin
```

How to find where to define the `/home/local/gradle-3.5.1/bin` and make `/home/local/gradle-5.3/bin` works.I define the `/home/local/gradle-5.3/bin` in bash_profile,but I could not find where to define `/home/local/gradle-3.5.1/bin` environment variable.Here is the path I aready checked:

```
/etc/profile
/root/.bash_profile
/home/dolphin/.bashrc
/home/dolphin/.bash_profile
```

PS: the OS is:Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: [How to determine where an environment variable came from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813/56041), [How to find where an environment variable is set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8058487/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using `find` and `grep`, there isn't much you can do to discover where each variable comes from.

Knowing that it is indeed an environment variable, I would attempt focusing the search in `/etc/` and your home directory. Replace `var` with the appropriate variable you're searching for:

`$ grep -r var /etc/*`

To print all the environment variables set in your shell, you can do the following:

`$ printenv | less`

Some places where to look for environment variables:

**System wide**

- `/etc/environment`: specifically meant for environment variables
- `/etc/env.d/*`: environment variables, split in multiple files
- `/etc/profile`: all types of initialization scripts
- `/etc/profile.d/*`: initialization scripts
- `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`: meant for functions and aliases

**User specific**

- `~/.bash_profile`: initialization for login (bash-)shells
- `~/.bashrc`: initialization for all interactive (bash-)shells
- `~/.profile`: used for all shells
- `~/.cshrc`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.tcshrc`: similar for non-bash shells

Comment: I found it on ~/.profile one by one by your tips,thank you.I already using find or grep command but it is too slow.@Paradox

Answer (score 0):

Google tells me that there may be a configuration file at:

```
/etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Under bash shell:

- To list all the environment variables, use the command " env " (or "
  printenv ").
- To reference a variable, use $varname , with a prefix '$' (Windows uses %varname% ).
- To print the value of a particular variable, use the command " echo
  $varname ".